# use url rewrite my page algnment differ

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

i use xampp v3.2.1 and os is windows 10 Prof.
here i use url rewrite using .htaccess file. its working fine in core php file. here i use bootstrap 2 template. when i use url rewrite its alignment is not proper. here i check the output using view->source and compare using online code tool . both output are same(identical). but result show is different. i attached the output

here my .htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /o2b2b/
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ search.php?=$1
</IfModule>
```

**original output**
[image]

**url rewrite used output**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

thanks i found the solution
please mention the  base path using this html tag

```
<base href="/o2b2b/" />
```